# エクリプスで作ったプロジェクトをいつでも実行可能なファイルにする

Tags: java

お世話になっています。エクリプスで作ったプロジェクトをいつでも実行可能な形(コマンドプロンプト等ではなくダブルクリックで起動するような形)にしたいのですが、初めてなのでどうすればよいかわかりません。一応自分でも調べ、エクスポートから.jarの形にしてみたのですがダブルクリックしても起動しませんでした。どうか、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 追記-------JREが入っている状態で実行してもやはり動きませんでした。特にエラーが出る様子はなくダブルクリックした後少秒読み込む動作をするのですが結局何も起きない感じです。

Comment: また、[http://pc-tech.distinct.main.jp/?eid=34]を参考に.exe化してみたのですが『jvm.dllをロードできませんでした。これを実行するには64bit-javaVMが必要です』という旨のエラーメッセージが出てきて実行できませんでした。また、exe化するにあたってコマンドプロンプトで『exewrap.exe -g -e SINGLE;NOLOG ファイル名.jar』という操作をしたところ『JavaVM (64-bit) not found.』と出ていました。

Comment: コマンドプロンプトで『java -jar  ○○.jar』としたところUnable to access jarfilieというエラーが出ました。

Answer (score 1):

適切なマニフェスト・ファイルを作らないと、実行可能なjarファイルにはなりません。

「executable jar」とか「実行可能 jar」などのキーワードでググってみましたか？たくさん情報はあると思いますよ。

例えば、このページはどうですか？

http://sunjava.seesaa.net/article/57546363.html

Comment: 参考にして操作してみたのですがやはり実行できませんでした。確認するべき場所などはあるのでしょうか？個人的にJREというものをちゃんとダウンロードした覚えがないのでそこに問題があるのかなと考えているのですが...

Comment: 予想された通り、たるたるポップさんの環境にJREがインストールされていないのが原因だと思います。インストールするか、またはEclipse に付属しているJRE を使ってjar を動かす方法がとれると思います。

Comment: Eclipseを実行するためにはJRE必須ですよ。
どこかに作成したJavaのプログラムを公開して、確認してもらうのがはやいのでは？

Answer (score 0):

Windows10を前提に記載します。また、記載したコマンドはPowerShellで実行しています。

サンプルコードは以下になります。ダブルクリックで開きたいということからおそらくGUIを持つアプリケーションだろう、ということでSwingを用いています。

- https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so39391

## 1. 前準備:  executable-jar を作成する

ここで言うexecutable-jarとは、下記のコマンドにより想定通り動作するようなファイルを指します。

```
java -jar <jarファイル名>
```

excecutable-jarはおおよそ次のような性質を持ちます:

- 実行に必要な `.class` ファイルが全てjarファイルに含まれている
- マニフェストに `Main-Class` 属性を持つ

(実のところ、executable-jarの作成は今回の質問を解決するうえで必須ではありませんが、問題をシンプルにするために行っておいた方が良いと考えます。)

### 選択肢a) Eclipse で executable-jar を作成する

(※ この方法はもはや主流ではありません。次に説明するMavenによる作成を試してみてください)

Project Explorer で今回のプロジェクトを右クリックし、 **Export > Runnable JAR file** から作成できます。
このとき、 Library handling の選択肢は "**Extract requred libraries into generated JAR**" を選択するようにしてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 選択肢b) Maven で executable-jar を作成する

Mavenパッケージであるなら、Eclipseのメニューから作成するより Maven plugin で解決した方がよいでしょう。
例えば maven-assembly-plugin を用いて次のように書けます。

```
  <!-- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html -->
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>com.github.yukihane.App</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

`mvn package` コマンド実行時に、通常のjarファイルと同時に、接尾に `-with-dependencies` が付与されたファイルも生成されるようになります。
これが executable-jar です。

## 2. executable-jar をダブルクリックで起動できるようにする

### 2.1. パブリックJRE

Java8までは、OracleのサイトからダウンロードできるJDK/JREインストーラでインストールすると、パブリックJREのインストールを選ぶことができました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

パブリックJREをインストールしていれば、jarファイルをダブルクリックした際にJVM上でプログラムが実行されるような設定が自動で行われていました。
この場合、特に意識することなく所望の動作になります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)などでjarをラップしexeファイル化することで、見た目などをネイティブ実行ファイルと変わらなくすることもできます。

```
  <!-- https://github.com/lukaszlenart/launch4j-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/README.adoc -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>l4j-gui</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>launch4j</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <headerType>gui</headerType>
          <outfile>target/myapp.exe</outfile>
          <jar>target/execjava-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar</jar>
          <classPath>
            <mainClass>com.github.yukihane.App</mainClass>
          </classPath>
          <jre>
            <minVersion>1.8.0</minVersion>
          </jre>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

今回の質問はおよそ2年前に行われていますが、当時はこれで問題なかったかと思います。
が、現在は利用できる状況は限られつつあります。
現在主流のJavaディストリビューションにはもはやパブリックJREは含まれないからです。

### 2.2. jpackage

https://jdk.java.net/jpackage/

アーリーアクセス(つまり、まだ正式版ではない)の段階ですが、jpackageも今回の目的に沿うプロダクトです。

冒頭に記載したリポジトリのコードでは、次のコマンドで作成できます:

```
mvn clean package
mkdir fatjar
mv .\target\execjava-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar .\fatjar\
jpackage --package-type app-image -d target -i fatjar -n myjpkg `
  --main-class com.github.yukihane.App `
  --main-jar execjava-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

`target\myjpkg` 以下のファイルが生成物(配布対象)です。
`myjpkg.exe` ダブルクリックで実行できます。

前述パブリックJRE方式は、実行するユーザの環境にあらかじめパブリックJREの導入が必要です。
一方、jpackageはランタイムを同梱するのでそのような前提はありません。(その分配布物のサイズが増加しますが)

### 2.3. GraalVM

https://www.graalvm.org/

[`native-image`](https://www.graalvm.org/docs/reference-manual/native-image/)コマンドでネイティブイメージ化する方法です。

```
native-image -jar .\fatjar\execjava-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar --no-fallback
```

試してみたところ残念ながら現在の最新版 `19.2.1` はまだ WindowsのSwingアプリケーションには対応できていないようですが、将来的には選択肢に含まれるかもしれません。

- [[native-image] Windows with a swing application #1327](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1327)

Comment: 本筋からは逸れるのですが、ランタイム同梱形式を選択する場合、ライセンスも気に掛ける必要があるかと思います。